# Best way to handle PHP-FPM with a ton of Pools

Tags: php-fpm, apache-2.4, amazon-linux

We recently upgraded to Apache 2.4 and want to move away from the Prefork + mpm-itk setup we had in 2.2 .  The problem is we host about 60 domains, and while we control the PHP development, we still want to have them isolated per domain, as over the years, we have had so many different developers, plugins, etc.

I understand we would have to create a FPM pool for every single domain, but how do we handle all the processes it will create?  Does anyone have any suggestions on how they handle and limit this, while not causing stability issues.

Comment: Without the knowledge of your requirements it's impossible to give reasonable advice.
But you can limit/tune php-fpm with parameters like "pm.max_children", "pm.start_servers" and "pm.max_requests". Play with the options until you have a setup that fits your requirements.

Comment: You will, most likely, need more memory.

Comment: We are currently running on a c3.large instance with 3.75gb of memory. Will the overhead savings from being able to switch away from Prefork allow us to run PHP-FPM?